# How do I say that an object is present in a Set that also has a treeset?

Tags: java, set, treeset

I have s set of object `A`.

```
Class A {

    String text1;
    String text2
    TreeSet<ClassAA> classAaSet;
    @Override 
    public boolean equals(object b){

    }
    @Override 
    public int hashCode(){

    }
}
```

The other class:

```
Class AA {
    String y;
    String z;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(y,z)
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ClassAA other) {
        return y.compareTo(other.y)
    }
}
```

I have a set of A's and a single Object `A`.
How do i `Set<A>aSet.contains(A)`?

Internally, since i have a treeset, its ignoring the equals implementation.

Comment: This question is very unclear.  If `A` is going to be put into a `Set` it must correctly implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`, which you have not done.  Also, your question doesn't mention `AA`.  How does `AA` fit into what you are asking?

Comment: What's `ClassAA`?

Comment: `java.util.TreeSet` uses `equals()` on the contained objects. Your problem may be the opposite: class `AA` does not implement `equals()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be clearer if you posted code that was correct to the extent that it could be compiled. Anyway:

Your class `AA` should fulfil three requirements: (1) equal objects should return the same `hashCode()`, (2) `compareTo()` should be consistent with `equals()`, and (3) for `compareTo()` and the `TreeSet` to work correctly, the class should implement `Comparable<AA>`.

I hope you can add the `implements` clause (3) on your own. For (2), look at the documentation of `Comparable`. The easiest fix is to override `equals()` to say that an `AA` is equal to another `AA` with the same `y`. Unfortunately, this would break (1) because the current `hashCode` method depends on `z` too.

So decide what it means for two `AA` objects to be equal. In other words, given `classAaSet` in `A` and an `AA` object, what it means that the set already contains such an `AA`. Is it enough for it to have the same `y` or should it have both the same `y` and the same `z`? Then code `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `compareTo()` to reflect your decision.

Actually, I believe that a `TreeSet` does not use `hashCode()`, so in a dirty solution you could live without fulfilling (1), even without overriding `hashCode()` at all. You could be in for trouble if your class was used in a new context some other time, so I wouldn’t recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create set of Class A's objects then you should override both equals and hashcode() method in Class A. You have added method equals() in class A but you have kept its definition block empty that is equal to not overriding or implementing that method. In last line you are saying its ignoring the Equals implementation but where is the implementation? It is not there. Question is not clear. Can you explain what exactly you are trying?

Comment: I am sorry.. Yes,i have kept it empty only for the question purpose.So i have a Set of A's(lets call it setOfA's) and each A has a Tree Set of AA's. I have another object of A(objOfA),thats not in setOfA's,which is identical to one of the objects in setOfA's,so that setOfAs.contains(objOfA) must return true.But since each A has a treeSet of elements,the treeset although has an equals overriden,does not get called there..